# Update source for multiple CKEditor5 instances

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor5

I have several fields on a form. Some of them are simple inputs, others are datetimepickers, a few of them are CKEditors. I handle the form submit manually, so I need to manually update the source fields for the CKEditor instances to get all modification before I save it to a MySQL database. I put all the instances to an array (I see its content in Chrome's web developer tool), but when I try to use destroy or updateSourceElement methods on one item from this array, I get "TypeError, item.updateSourceElement is not a function" messages.

I use this code:

```
const CKeditors = {};
```

...

```
function createEditor( elementId ) {
return ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( elementId ),
{
    toolbar: [ "heading", "|", "bold", "italic", "link", "bulletedList", "numberedList"]
})
.then( editor => {
    CKeditors[ elementId ] = editor;
})
    .catch( err => console.error( err.stack ) );
}

createEditor("#'.$mezo['mezonev'].'_tartalom");  // $mezo['mezonev'].'_tartalom is the unique name of the input field

function submitAllCKeditors(){
  for (item in CKeditors)
  { 
    item.updateSourceElement();
  }
}
```

...

and somewhere later when I handle the onlick event, I call "submitAllCKeditors();" I see the array's content with the proper ids, but I get error for the item.updateSourceElement();

What am I doing wrong?